# ImportError: Cannot import name 'Asset' bigchaindb

Tags: python, pip, blockchain, rethinkdb-python

I've installed bigchaindb correctly (I believe) but I keep getting an error when I run the following python command

from bigchaindb_driver import BigchaindDB

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .driver import BigchainDB   # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/driver.py", line 2, in <module>
from .offchain import prepare_transaction, fulfill_transaction
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/offchain.py", line 18, in <module>
from .utils import (
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/utils.py", line 9, in <module>
from bigchaindb.common.transaction import Asset
ImportError: cannot import name 'Asset'
```

Any ideas on what is causing the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at `bigchaindb.common.transaction` module [source code](https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/blob/master/bigchaindb/common/transaction.py) and it looks like there is no `Asset` name in this module. 
The reason might be that `Asset` was [removed](https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/commit/9319583ab41491f8fd84977c11bef2baf19e1776#diff-c03138cb428bd41d7c7bf527924b3d5c)  in newer version of `bigchaindb`.

So are you sure you have `bigchaindb_driver` version compatible with version of `bigchaindb` ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had installed bigchaindb using python3.4 and bigchaindb_driver using python3.5. I restarted the process using only python 3.4 and it works now.

N.B the bigchaindb documentation needs to be updated to install bigchaindb_driver, I  used:
    'pip3 install bigchaindb_driver'
instead of 
    'pip install bigchaindb_driver'